# How to output a determined number of characters in VHDL regardless of the input

Tags: vhdl, ram

I´m working on a code VHDL with a RAM memory which purpose is show me the output data in the TeraTerm software. I enter the data via the Arduino COM window (The Arduino MEGA 2560 is connected to an FPGA, an Altera DE10-Nano Kit, and then to the PC). The problem however is on the code, I want it to show me 80 characters and, if I enter a different number of characters (either less or more) I want it to show on the TeraTerm the data I typed in, plus 0´s filling the 80-character gap. This way, if I send a 80-character string it should never displace the characters. Currently if I send 80 characters it shows it correctly, but if I type another string of characters different than 80, the previous string repeats but with the previous string dragged in, displacing future strings. Take as an example the string:

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqr

80 characters long. I type it, it shows correct. Y type "ddddd", enter. It shows again "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqr". Then I type "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqr" again and it shows "dddddabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklm"

From here now, future characters will be displaced.

I want it to show like:
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqr"
"ddddd000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqr"

[image]

This is the current code. Thanks, I appreciate you help.

```
-- Quartus Prime VHDL Template
-- Single port RAM with single read/write address 

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Single_Port_Ram_V2 is

    port 
    (
        Clk      : in std_logic;
        Addr_Vec   : in std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
        Data         : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        WE           : in std_logic := '1';
        O_Data_0,   O_Data_1,   O_Data_2,   O_Data_3,   O_Data_4,   O_Data_5,   O_Data_6,   O_Data_7   : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        O_Data_8,   O_Data_9,   O_Data_1_0, O_Data_1_1, O_Data_1_2, O_Data_1_3, O_Data_1_4, O_Data_1_5 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        O_Data_1_6, O_Data_1_7, O_Data_1_8, O_Data_1_9, O_Data_2_0, O_Data_2_1, O_Data_2_2, O_Data_2_3 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        O_Data_2_4, O_Data_2_5, O_Data_2_6, O_Data_2_7, O_Data_2_8, O_Data_2_9, O_Data_3_0, O_Data_3_1 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        O_Data_3_2, O_Data_3_3, O_Data_3_4, O_Data_3_5, O_Data_3_6, O_Data_3_7, O_Data_3_8, O_Data_3_9 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        O_Data_4_0, O_Data_4_1, O_Data_4_2, O_Data_4_3, O_Data_4_4, O_Data_4_5, O_Data_4_6, O_Data_4_7 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        O_Data_4_8, O_Data_4_9, O_Data_5_0, O_Data_5_1, O_Data_5_2, O_Data_5_3, O_Data_5_4, O_Data_5_5 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        O_Data_5_6, O_Data_5_7, O_Data_5_8, O_Data_5_9, O_Data_6_0, O_Data_6_1, O_Data_6_2, O_Data_6_3 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        O_Data_6_4, O_Data_6_5, O_Data_6_6, O_Data_6_7, O_Data_6_8, O_Data_6_9, O_Data_7_0, O_Data_7_1 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        O_Data_7_2, O_Data_7_3, O_Data_7_4, O_Data_7_5, O_Data_7_6, O_Data_7_7, O_Data_7_8, O_Data_7_9 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        Out_Leds   : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0)
    );

end entity;

architecture rtl of Single_Port_Ram_V2 is

    -- Build a 2-D array type for the RAM
    subtype word_t is std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    type memory_t is array(127 downto 0) of word_t;

    type t_SM_Main is (Start, Stop);
   signal r_SM_Main : t_SM_Main := Start;

    -- Declare the RAM signal.  
    signal ram : memory_t;

    -- Register to hold the address 
    signal addr_reg : integer range 0 to 127;

   signal Addr_Int : integer range 0 to 127 := 0;


begin

    process(Clk, Addr_Vec)
    begin

    Addr_Int <= to_integer(unsigned(Addr_Vec));

    if(rising_edge(clk)) then
        if(WE = '1') then
            ram(Addr_Int) <= Data;
        end if;

    end if;
    end process;


    process(Clk)
    begin

       if rising_edge(Clk) then
         case r_SM_Main is
              when Start =>

                   if(Addr_Int = 79) then

             O_Data_0   <= ram(0);   
            O_Data_1   <= ram(1);
            O_Data_2   <= ram(2);
            O_Data_3   <= ram(3);
            O_Data_4   <= ram(4);
            O_Data_5   <= ram(5);
            O_Data_6   <= ram(6);
            O_Data_7   <= ram(7);
            O_Data_8   <= ram(8);
            O_Data_9   <= ram(9);
            O_Data_1_0 <= ram(10);
            O_Data_1_1 <= ram(11);
            O_Data_1_2 <= ram(12);
            O_Data_1_3 <= ram(13);
            O_Data_1_4 <= ram(14);
            O_Data_1_5 <= ram(15);
            O_Data_1_6 <= ram(16);
            O_Data_1_7 <= ram(17);
            O_Data_1_8 <= ram(18); 
            O_Data_1_9 <= ram(19);
            O_Data_2_0 <= ram(20);
            O_Data_2_1 <= ram(21);
            O_Data_2_2 <= ram(22);
            O_Data_2_3 <= ram(23);
            O_Data_2_4 <= ram(24);
            O_Data_2_5 <= ram(25);
            O_Data_2_6 <= ram(26);
            O_Data_2_7 <= ram(27);
            O_Data_2_8 <= ram(28);
            O_Data_2_9 <= ram(29);
            O_Data_3_0 <= ram(30);
            O_Data_3_1 <= ram(31);
            O_Data_3_2 <= ram(32);
            O_Data_3_3 <= ram(33);
            O_Data_3_4 <= ram(34);
            O_Data_3_5 <= ram(35);
            O_Data_3_6 <= ram(36);
            O_Data_3_7 <= ram(37);
            O_Data_3_8 <= ram(38);
            O_Data_3_9 <= ram(39);
            O_Data_4_0 <= ram(40);
            O_Data_4_1 <= ram(41);
            O_Data_4_2 <= ram(42);
            O_Data_4_3 <= ram(43);
            O_Data_4_4 <= ram(44);
            O_Data_4_5 <= ram(45);
            O_Data_4_6 <= ram(46);
            O_Data_4_7 <= ram(47);
            O_Data_4_8 <= ram(48);
            O_Data_4_9 <= ram(49);
            O_Data_5_0 <= ram(50); 
            O_Data_5_1 <= ram(51);
            O_Data_5_2 <= ram(52);
            O_Data_5_3 <= ram(53);
            O_Data_5_4 <= ram(54);
            O_Data_5_5 <= ram(55);
            O_Data_5_6 <= ram(56);
            O_Data_5_7 <= ram(57);
            O_Data_5_8 <= ram(58);
            O_Data_5_9 <= ram(59);
            O_Data_6_0 <= ram(60);
            O_Data_6_1 <= ram(61);
            O_Data_6_2 <= ram(62);
            O_Data_6_3 <= ram(63);  
            O_Data_6_4 <= ram(64);
            O_Data_6_5 <= ram(65);
            O_Data_6_6 <= ram(66);
            O_Data_6_7 <= ram(67); 
            O_Data_6_8 <= ram(68);
            O_Data_6_9 <= ram(69);
            O_Data_7_0 <= ram(70);
            O_Data_7_1 <= ram(71);
            O_Data_7_2 <= ram(72);
            O_Data_7_3 <= ram(73);
            O_Data_7_4 <= ram(74);
            O_Data_7_5 <= ram(75);
            O_Data_7_6 <= ram(76);
            O_Data_7_7 <= ram(77);
            O_Data_7_8 <= ram(78);
            O_Data_7_9 <= ram(79);

                    r_SM_Main <= Stop;

                else

--                  r_SM_Main <= Start;

             end if;  

                when Stop =>
                    r_SM_Main <= Start;

            end case;
       end if;      

    end process;

   Out_Leds <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(Addr_Int, Out_Leds'length));


end rtl;
```

Comment: Do you have any delimiters on your entered string?  That is, do you have any special character or signal to mark the start or end of a string?  If not, how is the system to know when a new string is entered?

Comment: Not sure if the problem is inside your ram structure, what happens outside e.g. with the `Addr_Vec`?